# Primefaces args.validationFailed is true but no validation message

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I submit some fields with a button:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msgs['label.button.editPropertiesSave']}" update=":editPropertyFormId:editPropertiesDialogContentId @(.resultlistActionGrid) " process=":editPropertyFormId:editPropertiesDialogContentId @this"  action="#{editPropertyBL.save()}" oncomplete="resetDocValueChangedIfValidationOk();" />


function resetDocValueChangedIfValidationOk(args) {
    if (args) {
        if (!args.validationFailed) {
            resetDocValueChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If I submit it with valid input the backing bean method `editPropertyBL.save()` is called but `args.validationFailed` is `true` and my javascript is not executed.
I have a `p:messages autoUpdate="true"` in the page which shows an info message about the saving but it does not show any validation error.
Why can `args.validationFailed` be true at this situation?
Regards
Oliver

Comment: one of the reasons is because you do something in your save method that makes it true or you might even set it to true explicitly... we cannot tell since the code you posted is not an mcve

Comment: I have to make a mcve in my free time. Too complex to strip it down now.